# How to enumerate a list within a list that was enumerated

Tags: python, loops, nested, arcpy, enumerate

The lists are made up as I do not have my code in front of me.

I have one list that has two items: `listA = [Region1, Region2]`

Within those lists (they are objects with embedded information originally) they each have a set of items. frame1 has three items; let's say `layer1 = [VA, GA, NC]` and frame2 has two items; `layer2 = [WI, MI]`.

So, hierarchically:

```
Region1:  
    VA  
    GA  
    NC  
Region2:  
    WI  
    MI
```

What I am trying to do is enumerate the parent layers to be:

```
0 Region1
1 Region2
```

While also enumerating from each respective sublist so the result would look something like:

```
0 Region1  
0 VA  
1 GA  
2 NC  
1 Region2  
0 WI  
1 MI
```

The first enumeration is simple, but I am lost on how to enumerate properly using any nested loop. I keep getting all 5 layers for each frame no matter how I've gone about it.

Any tips, tricks, ideas? I specifically need this to work with the basic enumerate function; not the Enum module.

Comment: Provide an actual working example that conveys the problem you're having - as it is, it's a little difficult to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Are these really lists (so I'd expect to see `[` and `]`) - or are they tuples? Or are they dictionaries?

Comment: Also, how have you tried going about it?

Comment: My apologies as I'm horribly new to any programming language....fixed the list "[ ]" error.

Comment: I attempted something to the effect of:

for i, v in enumerate(listA):  
    print i, v  
    for d, v in enumerate(layer1):  
        print.....  
But that is where I get lost. I ultimately end up with the two main ones (Region 1, Region2) properly marked and all five layer entries under both. I can't seem to break them out properly.

Answer (score 1):

Following the example shared by @Reblochon Masque,

```
>>> listA = [['abc', 'def'], ['ghi', 'klm'], ['nop', 'qrs']]                    >>> [(index,region) for index,region in enumerate(listA)]
[(0, ['abc', 'def']), (1, ['ghi', 'klm']), (2, ['nop', 'qrs'])]
>>> [(index,[(ind,it) for ind,it in enumerate(region)]) for index,region in enumerate(listA)]
[(0, [(0, 'abc'), (1, 'def')]), (1, [(0, 'ghi'), (1, 'klm')]), (2, [(0, 'nop'), (1, 'qrs')])]
>>> [("Region %d"%index,[(ind,it) for ind,it in enumerate(region)]) for index,region in enumerate(listA)]
[('Region 0', [(0, 'abc'), (1, 'def')]), ('Region 1', [(0, 'ghi'), (1, 'klm')]), ('Region 2', [(0, 'nop'), (1, 'qrs')])]

>>> format printing the list comprehension
>>> print "\n".join("Region %d \n%s"%(index,"\n".join("%d %s"%(ind,it) for ind,it in enumerate(region)))  for index,region in enumerate(listA))
Region 0
0 abc
1 def
Region 1
0 ghi
1 klm
Region 2
0 nop
1 qrs
```

Answer (score 0):

You iterate over the outer, and the inner enumerations:

```
listA = [['abc', 'def'], ['ghi', 'klm'], ['nop', 'qrs']]
for idx, inner in enumerate(listA):
    print('Region', idx)
    for jdx, elt in enumerate(inner):
        print(jdx, elt)
```

#### output:

```
Region 0
0 abc
1 def
Region 1
0 ghi
1 klm
Region 2
0 nop
1 qrs
```